# linking two css classes in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am new CSS styles and HTML.I have css file called layout.css in which we have a class  called

```
.Grid {
    width:100%; 
    direction:rtl
}
.tblsMonth {
    direction :rtl
}
```

I have created another css file with class as below:

```
.textdirection {direction:ltr}
```

Can i make for `.Grid` and `.tblsMonth` direction property to read from my css file `.textdirection`

Comment: as far as i know, you can't do it with pure CSS

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: yes you may use it like

.Grid.textdirection so that it will override your above css

Comment: @ManojMeena: then it would be .Grid.textdirection {width:100%;} and i have replace .Grid to .Grid.textdirection in all the pages where .Grid has been used..Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: you just need to replace .textdirection {direction:ltr} to .Grid.textdirection {direction:ltr} into your css file not for all pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't combine them in the CSS, but you can in HTML:

**direction.css**

```
.textdirection {direction:ltr}
```

**layout.css**

```
.Grid {
    width:100%; 
}
.tblsMonth {
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class"Grid textdirection"></div>
```